# With TraMineR, how to determine the number of transitions in individual sequences per type of transition?

Tags: traminer

In `TraMineR`, the function `seqtransn` allows to compute the number of transitions in individual sequences.

I was wondering : with `TraMineR`, is there a way to determine the number of transitions in individual sequences, but per type of transition?

For example, if I have state sequences with three distinct states, I will have 6 possible transitions. And I'd like to count, for each individual, the number of occurrences of each of the 6 possible transitions.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I show you here with the first 3 sequences of the `biofam` data how you can get the counts of the different possible transitions per sequence:

```
data(biofam)
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[1:3,10:25])

## First, make each sequence an element of a list    
biofam.seq.list <- setNames(split(biofam.seq, seq(nrow(biofam.seq))), rownames(biofam.seq))

## and apply seqtrate to each element of the list
tr.count <- lapply(biofam.seq.list, seqtrate, count=TRUE)
tr.count

## $`1167`
##        [-> 0] [-> 1] [-> 3] [-> 6]
## [0 ->]      8      0      1      0
## [1 ->]      0      0      0      0
## [3 ->]      0      0      0      1
## [6 ->]      0      0      0      5
##
## $`514`
##        [-> 0] [-> 1] [-> 3] [-> 6]
## [0 ->]      0      1      0      0
## [1 ->]      0      9      1      0
## [3 ->]      0      0      0      1
## [6 ->]      0      0      0      3
##
## $`1013`
##        [-> 0] [-> 1] [-> 3] [-> 6]
## [0 ->]      6      1      0      0
## [1 ->]      0      4      1      0
## [3 ->]      0      0      0      1
## [6 ->]      0      0      0      2
```

Comment: Hi. Nice solution. Thank you for your help!  Best.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but please see the help page [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).